# Do we need to explicitly mention which column is foreign key column?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

When we create relational database tables, we have to use foreign key columns. It is obvious, otherwise we can not create relationships.

However, I noticed that it is enough to have a foreign key column, you do not need to say that there is a foreign key relationship in table A with table B.

As long as you can write the queries you can retrieve the data.

Do we use this concept for make thing easy? I know, when I look at a database table schema which has marked what columns are foreign key columns, it is easy to understand and start to work with it.

Is there any other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we create relational database tables, we have to use foreign key
>   columns. It is obvious, otherwise we can not create relationships.

Incorrect. You do not *need* to create foreign keys (though it's a good idea), and they do not represent relationships. They enforce the integrity of the relationship. A foreign key makes sure that a value in one column exists in another column.

> However, I noticed that it is enough to have a foreign key column, you
>   do not need to say that there is a foreign key relationship in table A
>   with table B. As long as you can write the queries you can retrieve the data.

Yes, the relationship is based on the data itself, not by the inclusion of a foreign key. Also, foreign keys do not need to be between two tables, a table can have a foreign key to itself.

> Do we use this concept for make thing easy?

No, we use foreign keys to enforce integrity. That they happen to make ERD diagrams easier to understand is simply a bonus.

Comment: `foreign keys do not need to be between two tables, a table can have a foreign key to itself.` Could you please provide an example for this?

Comment: @mankadanka create table employees ( id int primary key, name text, supervisor_id int references employees.id);

Answer (score 2):

The point is [Referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity). If you don't enforce it, sooner or later a bug in the code or some other accident happens and your database is left in an inconsistent state. These inconsistencies are very hard or impossible to fix afterwards.